# "Форт Росс"

Tags: орфография, топонимика

Здравствуйте! Как правильно пишется и склоняется название поселения Форт Росс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не очень официально, то так. 
Современное название - Форт-Росс, это как бы обратный перевод с английского, поэтому склоняется второе слово: Форт-Росса, Форт-Россу и т.д., как это обычно и имеет место с иностранными названиями. 
Что же касается истории, то два столетия назад основанное поселение носило название "Форт Росс", склонялись оба слова. В этом смысле автор романа и съемочная группа не погрешили против исторической правды.

На всякий случай давайте попросим кого-нибудь заглянуть в современный словарь географических названий, у меня его под рукой, увы, нет.

Comment: Но Форт -- в любом случае с большой буквы?

Comment: Да, конечно! Это же имя собственное.
Хотя... Вы знаете, посмотрел по нацкорпусу - встречаются оба варианта написания исторического поселения. Форт - с заглавной и со строчной. Ноя всё-таки за заглавную. Первое слово - часть названия, без него не используется.